# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase, snakeyaml

I want to migrate snakeyaml to 2.0 and that forced me to migrate liquibase from 4.9.0 to 4.21.1
same for spring boot from 2.5.13 to 2.7.x

but I get this error of liquibase :

```
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
      Position : 24 [Failed SQL: (0) SET SEARCH_PATH TO database-name, "$user","database-name"]
        at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:235)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$0(Liquibase.java:237)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:194)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:172)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:1618)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:229)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:213)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:329)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
        ... 160 common frames omitted
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
      Position : 24 [Failed SQL: (0) SET SEARCH_PATH TO database-name, "$user","database-name"]
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:337)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:254)
        at liquibase.command.core.helpers.LockServiceCommandStep.run(LockServiceCommandStep.java:38)
        at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:212)
        ... 172 common frames omitted
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
      Position : 24 [Failed SQL: (0) SET SEARCH_PATH TO database-name, "$user","database-name"]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:445)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:77)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:160)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125)
        at liquibase.database.core.DatabaseUtils.initializeDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:61)
        at liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase.rollback(PostgresDatabase.java:403)
        at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:292)
        ... 175 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
      Position : 24
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:335)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:321)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:297)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:292)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:441)
        ... 181 common frames omitted
```

I couldn't understand the error. I tried to add quotes on the database name on the application-common.yml but nothing changed.

Is there a problem with the version compatibilities or should I update something in the code?

This is my pom.xml with the new versions I put:

if something else needed I can provide

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Add AF (or KL) parent pom -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.afklm.maven.pom</groupId>
        <artifactId>af-projects-pom</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.afklm.mcfc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mcfc-ss</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mcfc-ss</name>
    <description>Management of Commercial and Facilities Cards</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <sonar.java.source>1.8</sonar.java.source>
        <sonar.java.target>1.8</sonar.java.target>
        
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.11</spring-boot.version>
        
        <h2.version>2.1.212</h2.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.6.0</postgresql.version> <!-- TODO get the official version OR get version from parent AFKL POM ? -->
        <liquibase.version>4.21.1</liquibase.version>
        <hibernate-custom-dialect.version>1.0.0</hibernate-custom-dialect.version>
        
        <habile.version>3.0.5</habile.version>
        <habile-simul.version>3.1.1</habile-simul.version>
        <sdfw.version>3.2.3</sdfw.version> <!-- v3.3.3 n'accepte pas les définitions de WS contenant des variables comme sdfw.ws.id... devrait être fixé plus tard... -->
        <ws-security.version>1.0</ws-security.version>
        
        <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.2.6</cucumber.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
        <xbean.version>3.11.1</xbean.version>
        <togglz.version>2.6.1.Final</togglz.version>
        <glassfish-plf.version>4.1.1</glassfish-plf.version>
        
        <kafka-clients.version>1.0.0</kafka-clients.version>
        <como-logback-appender.version>1.0.2</como-logback-appender.version>
        <logback-contrib.version>0.1.5</logback-contrib.version>
        
        <janino.version>3.0.6</janino.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
        
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
           **/com/afklm/mcfc/api/**/*,
           **/com/afklm/mcfc/commons/datamodel/**/entity/**/*,
           **/com/afklm/mcfc/commons/dto/**/*,
           **/com/afklm/mcfc/commons/externalws/impl/**/*
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        
    </properties>
    
    <modules>
        <module>mcfcCommons</module>
        <module>mcfcApi</module>
        <module>mcfcBatchs</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.mcfc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mcfcCommons</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
                <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${togglz.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
                <artifactId>togglz-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${togglz.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            
            <!-- Logging into Kafka for COMO -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                <version>${kafka-clients.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.tecc</groupId>
                <artifactId>como-logback-appender</artifactId>
                <version>${como-logback-appender.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
        
            <!-- Logging for Json formatting through logback -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${logback-contrib.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>${logback-contrib.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
              <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
              <version>${janino.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Togglz testing support -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
              <artifactId>togglz-testing</artifactId>
              <version>${togglz.version}</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.teccse.hibernateCustomDialect</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernateCustomDialect</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-custom-dialect.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Filter Habile -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.springboot.habile</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-habile</artifactId>
                <version>${habile.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <!-- habile simul -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.springboot.habile</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-habile-simul</artifactId>
                <version>${habile-simul.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.stubs</groupId>
                <artifactId>w000479-v01</artifactId>
                <version>0</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- YAML fix, waiting for Spring Boot dependencies update fix -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
              <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
              <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Lombok -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Don't know why but (optionally) needed when adding Spring security habile v3... -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.glassfish.pfl</groupId>
              <artifactId>pfl-basic</artifactId>
              <version>${glassfish-plf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Import dependency management from SDFW (Web Services) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.jaxws</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdfw-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${sdfw.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- SOA framework -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.jaxws</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdfw-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${sdfw.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.jaxws</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdfw-consumer-deps</artifactId>
                <version>${sdfw.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.jaxws</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdfw-provider-deps</artifactId>
                <version>${sdfw.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        
            <!-- SOAP/jms -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.jaxws</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdfw-async-deps</artifactId>
                <version>${sdfw.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Invoking SOAP over JMS -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.afklm.soa.jaxws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${sdfw.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
                <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${xbean.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- WS Security : Holds the credentials for each environment for WS calls -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.airfrance.soa.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>mcfc-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>${ws-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <!-- Cucumber -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/database.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin-postgresql.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.validation-api.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
      <resources> 
        <resource> 
          <filtering>true</filtering> 
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory> 
        </resource> 
      </resources> 
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm obliged to use sankeyaml 2.0, therefore I can't downgrade it

Comment: "database-name" can be translated to "database minus name". You could use an underscore _ to solve the issue

Comment: I can't change the name of the database i found this work around : 
System.setProperty(GlobalConfiguration.PRESERVE_SCHEMA_CASE.getKey(), "true");
but i don't know where to put it !